# How to get IE 10 to show scrollbars on iframe

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Since time immemorial, if you write:

```
<iframe scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Then, regardless of the content of the iframe, scroll bars are shown. If, like me, you use iframes a lot to display tabular data - with the table header outside the iframe, it is important to know that the scrollbars will always appear, so you can allow for the width of the scrollbar when making the table headings line up with the columns in the data.

So, what do you have to do to get IE 10 to display scroll bars on an iframe with scrolling="yes" set? If the content does not exceed the size of the iframe - IE 10 DOES NOT SHOW Scrollbars!

Here's a fiddle.[Example of scrollbars not showing](http://jsfiddle.net/qLu9V/) View it in Firefox and the scrollbars show. View it in IE 9 and the scroll bars show. View it in IE 10 and they don't.

Comment: No, Not here. http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/179/cc6b727651b44c0da3ec93f.png

Comment: What is that image below the fiddle? How do you view that?

Comment: It's [IE's Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18359). You can toggle it with F12 Key.

Comment: @Sonu Joshi - thanks for that. This is a very old site. Looking at the developer toolbar - I am running the site in IE 10 Compatability mode (and the iframe scroll bars are now showing) but Document Mode is IE5 quirks.

Any suggestions on a doctype for an 8 year old site that has never really been updated.

Answer (score -2):

Note that WebKit browsers also don't show scroll bars.

If you set overflow: scroll; to the root (HTML) element of the document that will be used in the iframe, it will show the scroll bars as expected.

```
   html { overflow: scroll; }
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of it in action]

Comment: Does not work for me. I have added it to the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qLu9V/2/ and it adds scroll bars to the area containing the iframe, but not to the iframe itself.

Comment: You added it to the parent HTML file. You want to add it to the html document referenced by the iframe. You can't add that with JS fiddle as you used a png, which you can't add css styles to. I've added a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: @DavidStorey This does not work for me. Were you able to get it to work? (I have two files: `host.html` and `iframecontents.html`. I added the style to the `iframecontents.html`. Is that correct? If yes, then it doesn't work)