# IE 10 does not display scrollbars on iframe even with scrolling="yes" and overflow: scroll

Tags: css, html, iframe, internet-explorer-10

I have an iframe that has content which is too long for the iframe. I set the CSS to `overflow: auto;` and added the HTML attribute `scrolling="yes"`. In Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome, scrollbars appear. In IE10, they do not and some of the content gets cut off.

How do I get scrollbars to appear?

Comment: does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429894/how-to-get-ie-10-to-show-scrollbars-on-iframe

Comment: @Serv no, it does not work.

Comment: post a little fiddle, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: working fine for me with IE10, even without any attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/4Fp2P/

Answer (score 0):

instead of `overflow:auto;`, try `overflow:scroll`; which makes it auto. I had a similar problem and it worked for me.